# Callback function ignoring other validation rules and executes first

Tags: php, codeigniter

On the HTML form, I have a field such as:

```
<?php
     $token = array(
       'name'          => 'pc_token',
       'id'            => 'pc_token',
       'class'         => 'form-control'           
       );
     echo form_input($token, set_value('pc_token')); ?>
```

The validation rules set on the field are:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'pc_token', 'Token number', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|callback_token_exists',
     array(
       'required'      =>  'You have not provided %s.',
       'token_exists'  =>  'The %s is not valid. Please recheck again'                 
       )
     );
```

And here is the function for the callback

```
public function token_exists($key)
{        
    $this->load->model('tokens');
    return $this->tokens->IsValidToken($key); // will return true if found in database or false if not found
}
```

The problem here is that when I keep the `pc_token` field empty/blank and submit the form, I don't get the expected error message printed on screen.

## Current Output

> The Token number is not valid. Please recheck again

## Expected Output

> You have not provided Token number

So why does CI ignore the previous rules (such as `required`, `min_length` etc) in this case? If my assumption is correct, the direction is left to right and if even one fails, it does not move to the next rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your `callback function`

check for `empty`

```
public function token_exists($key='')
{   

  if(empty($key)){
         $this->form_validation->set_message('token_exists', 'The {field} field is   required.');
         return FALSE;
   }else{
      $this->load->model('tokens');
      return $this->tokens->IsValidToken($key); 
    }

// will return true if found in database or false if not found
}
```

Comment: I'll definitely test this and by the looks of things, it should work. But my question remains unanswered. Why is the callback function taking preference over other rules?

Also, I'll have to also add checks for min_length and max_length if I take this route which is counterproductive.

Comment: Unfortunately, as described in the code from CI, callbacks validation rules are always verified first, prior to ‘required’ for instance.

There is an official issue opened at CI : https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/5077

Comment: That's interesting. It's from 2017 and I'm surprised that it hasn't been addressed yet, perhaps CI4 will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the approach that I took. But I'll accept Abhishek's answer as he led me in the right direction. It's a bit sad that CI3 did not address it so I'm forced to use an alternate approach.

So, the validation rules become:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'pc_token', 'Token number', 'callback_token_exists'
     );
```

And the callback function becomes:

```
public function token_exists($key)
{
    if(trim($key) == "" || empty($key))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('token_exists', 'You have not provided %s.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else if(strlen($key) < 5)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('token_exists', '%s should be at least 5 characters long.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else if(strlen($key) > 12)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('token_exists', '%s cannot be greater than 12 characters long.');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('tokens');
        $isValid = $this->tokens->IsValidToken($key);
        if(! $isValid)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('token_exists', 'You have not provided %s.');           
        }

        return $isValid;
    }   
}
```